# In MacVim I can't get the command character to map

Tags: macvim

I read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40990454/how-to-map-mac-command-key-in-vim that you can get the command key to map in MacVim

I have installed MacVim with brew, using `brew cask install macvim`

I have MacVim in the terminal `/usr/local/bin/vim`,  and I see MacVim in the finder.

I start MacVim from the finder

I can see it access ~/.vim/vimrc fine as it reads my first line of `:set shortmess=I`

This is my vimrc

```
~$ cat ~/.vim/vimrc
:set shortmess=I


map <D-a> iaaaa
map <D-b> iaaaa
map <D-c> iaaaa
map <D-d> iaaaa
map <D-e> iaaaa
map <D-f> iaaaa
map <D-g> iaaaa
map <D-h> iaaaa
map <D-i> iaaaa
map <D-j> iaaaa
map <D-k> iaaaa
map <D-l> iaaaa
map <D-m> iaaaa
map <D-n> iaaaa
map <D-o> iaaaa
map <D-p> iaaaa
map <D-q> iaaaa
map <D-r> iaaaa
map <D-s> iaaaa
map <D-t> iaaaa
map <D-u> iaaaa
map <D-v> iaaaa
map <D-w> iaaaa
map <D-x> iaaaa
map <D-y> iaaaa
map <D-z> iaaaa

map <C-a> ibbbb

map <leader>1 iaaaa
:map <leader>0 iaaaa

~$
```

I can't get any of my command character mappings to work

Control maps fine, and leader works too. But i'm curious re command character.

I seem to get similar result with starting MacVim from finder, as I do starting MacVim(that's the vim I use) from Terminal.